# Passing variable from controller scope to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my controller I've defined `$scope.worker` which is a plain JS object:

```
{
    name: 'Peter',
    phone: 601002003
}
```

I've created a directive:

```
.directive('phoneType', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
        }
    };
}])
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<span phone-type="worker.phone"></span>
```

How do I pass `worker.phone` (in this example 601002003) from the controller scope to the directive, so I can create my logic in the `link` method? `attrs.phoneType` right now shows me `worker.phone` string.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could also pass the value to the directive via two way binding:

```
.directive('phoneType', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
          phoneNumber: '=phoneType'
        }
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // now do stuff with the number, you can access it through the scope
            scope.phoneNumber // contains the number
        }
    };
}])
```

Now you can access the number directly through the isolate scope.
Template would look like this:

```
<span phone-type="worker.phone"></span>
```

By the way, you don't need the restrict A. This is the default behavior.

Comment: I much prefer this solution

Comment: scope.phoneType won't update though if worker.phone updates. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @thelamborghinistory It depends on where you use the phonyType scope property. If you solely use it in the directive's view it should update automatically due to the two-way binding nature. If you want to trigger other actions in the directive controller you have to set up a $watch on the scope property in order to be notified when the property changes.
Does this help? Feel free to provide a jsFiddle, which describes your problem.