# Creating new scope in AngularJS template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to add a new scope in an AngularJS template?

```
<button ng-click="modifier + 1 if inactive or modifier - 1 if inactive">{{someNumber + modifier}}</button>
```

Basically the button will have an 'active' state or 'inactive' state.

On 'active', the modifier will increase, on 'inactive' it will go back to normal.

But let's say I have 100 of these buttons. I can make variables like modifier-1, modifier-2,.... but that's not best practice.

How do I make a new scope within this template so I can keep modifier as a variable name throughout the 100 buttons?

Comment: Is each variable deffernt in each button event or same?

Comment: modifier is different for each button

Comment: you can create them in `ng-repeat` loop.

Comment: the problem is that the buttons are all over the place

Comment: also sorry, no the modifier is the same. but when you click the button it will only increase the modifier for that button.

Answer (score 0):

from your question I understand that the scope needs be same for all the buttons, so I suggest the below code, if the snippet is correct use it to build you code, the directive contains an isolated scope so that the controller variable does not affect the directive variable and the values for modifier and somevalue are written inside the directive, if you want this to pass from the controller, pass the variables through the scope. refer: [pass variable from controller to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612977/passing-variable-from-controller-scope-to-directive)

```js
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    
    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [{
            salutation: 'Hello',
            name: 'World'
        }, {
            salutation: 'Konichiwa',
            name: 'Mr. Roboto'
        }];
         $scope.test = "nare";
    }]);

    myApp.directive('customButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        template: '<button ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(100) track by $index" ng-click="modifiertoggle()">{{output}}</button>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         scope.somevalue = 100;
          scope.modifier = {value:32, state: 'active'};
          scope.output = scope.somevalue - scope.modifier.value;
          console.log(scope.output);
          scope.modifiertoggle = function(){
           scope.modifier.state = scope.modifier.state === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active';
            if(scope.modifier.state === 'active'){
            scope.output = scope.somevalue - scope.modifier.value;
            }else{
            scope.output = scope.somevalue + scope.modifier.value;
            }
          }
        }
    };
});
```

```css
button{
  height:50px;
  width:75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MyController'>
    <custom-button></custom-button>
</div>
```